# How to skip non-object error in PHP mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, syntax-error, fatal-error

When having an error in SQL syntax in classic PHP mysql, the query will not take place without any other effect. But in mysqli, it will kill the PHP script with Fatal error

```
mysql_query("SELECT title, misspelled_column FROM posts");

$mysqli->query("SELECT title, misspelled_column FROM posts");
```

In the first case, it will show the other queries and php output; but the second case kills the script by

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

The problem is related to `non-object` returned by false query. I can skip this error by

```
if($result){$row = $result->fetch_assoc();}
```

but my question is that why I did not need this check in classic `mysql`? With a more advanced system, one expects new features not missing what we had.

Comment: fix the errors. problem solved.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to handle MySQL syntax errors because these should be taken care of during the development phase. And never, ever use the error suppression operator for something like that.

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: I agree, it sometimes seems weird that mysqli is less convenient to use than mysql was. On the other hand, most of the things mysqli forbids you to do are things we should never have done in the first place. Two big examples are writing non-parameterized queries or trying to use the results of a query without making sure that they exist. Being able to do that may be convenient, but it's also a huge security hole or application crash waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error generated by MySQL should not be stopping execution. In fact, you can have your script show you any SQL errors by using `$mysqli->error` (assuming `$mysqli` is your database connection, like in your example). However, what may be happening is that your mysqli error causes a particular object not to be created, and then calling a method on that object will create a fatal PHP error. For example:

```
$dbconn = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("bluh"); // not a valid statement. fails to create a mysqli statement object in $stmt.
echo($dbconn->error); // your script is still running, and this will show your MySQL syntax error.
$stmt->execute();
```

This will die not because you made an SQL error, but because `$stmt` was null and didn't have the expected `execute()` method. So like everyone else has said, check your logs and see what the actual error is.

Using `@` to ignore errors is going to be hit-or-miss until you figure out which specific command is creating the error.

**update:** If you know that the error is in the query, then you could check to see whether the query succeeded before you try to do anything with it. One way is to check the `error` parameter; another is to check to make sure that it actually returned the kind of object you want.

Here are examples of both:

```
$result = $db->query("select firstname, lastname from people where firstname = 'egbert';");
if($db->error == '') {
     // the query worked, so fetch results from $result and do stuff with them.
}
else {
     // the query didn't work, so don't try to do anything with $result
}

// alternately:
if(gettype($result) == "object") {
     // the query worked.
}
else {
     // it didn't.
}
```

Comment: I've followed my errors and they are exactly due to the reason you quoted; but I have no idea how to avoid fatal error because of mysqli no-object output.

Comment: In that case, it would probably help for you to post the code that's actually giving you errors -- the example code you gave in your question isn't enough.

Comment: You could just test to see if the query succeeded, and skip any further operations if it failed. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Also, I think your question is still wrong: misspelling a column in your query **does not** cause the script to die. It only dies later on when you try to do something with the result of the bad query.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL error doesn't kill mysqli in my experience.  I suspect you actually have a PHP error in the relevant statement.  Check your error log.

In PHP, you can use `@` to suppress errors.  It's **a bad idea** to use it here.  But if that's what you really want, it's documented at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php.

Comment: it is NOT "usually" but ALWAYS a bad idea. And it's apparently not what the OP NEEDED.

Comment: a usual "I read only question title and don't bug myself with reading the body" answer. "how to ignore an error" keyword triggers an automated answer. No mind involved. I wonder why SO don't have such a feature programmed in already, making enthusiasts obsolete.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel The story is not like what you said. There should be something in my PHP settings causing fatal error because of syntax error. Since I recently moved from mysql to mysqli; I asked if someone can give me a hint how to setup PHP to avoid this.